# Как обнаружить ошибку при вводе из istream_iterator<int>

Tags: c++, stl, vector, ввод, итераторы

Хочу заполнить вектор со стандартного потока ввода `cin` с использованием `std::istream_iterator`.
Есть такой код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<vector>

int main()
{
  std::istream_iterator< int > in(std::cin);
  std::istream_iterator< int > end;
  typedef std::vector< int > int_vector;
  int_vector data;
  std::back_insert_iterator< int_vector > target(data);
  while (in != end)
  {
    *target = *in;
    ++in;
    ++target;
  }
  std::ostream_iterator<int> out(std::cout, ", ");
  std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), out);
  return 0;
}
```

Отсюда два **вопроса**:

1. Как корректно завершить ввод?
2. Как решить проблему с неверным вводом
       (введут не `int`, а `double` например)?

Comment: А Вы можете выбрать для завершения ввода некоторый символ?

Comment: @Jenssen нет, надо читать поток до состояния EOF.

Comment: My fault, тогда остался второй вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in == end` в конце ввода (EOF) или если любая ошибка ввода произошла. Поэтому если цикл у вас преждевременно завершится, то это значит что произошла ошибка. Её можно обнаружить, проверив достиг ли ввод конца: `cin.eof()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::istream_iterator<int> numbers { std::cin  }, eof;

  // populate vector
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::copy(numbers, eof, std::back_inserter(v));

  // print vector
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
  return !std::cin.eof(); // success on eof
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/h47mnr).

Что равнозначно:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  // populate vector
  std::vector<int> v;
  for (int n; std::cin >> n; )
    v.push_back(n);

  // print vector
  for (int n : v)
    std::cout << n << '\n';

  return !std::cin.eof(); // success on eof
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/kZUspH).